# QML как изменять MapPolyline path из C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, xubuntu

Есть QML карта:

```
Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmMapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
        zoomLevel: 14

        MapPolyline {
            line.width: 3
            line.color: 'red'
            path: [
                { latitude: -27, longitude: 153.0 },
                { latitude: -27, longitude: 154.1 },
                { latitude: -28, longitude: 153.5 },
                { latitude: -29, longitude: 153.5 }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Каким образом можно изменять `path` из С++/qt? Я пытался так:

```
map = new QQuickWidget();
map->setSource(QUrl("qrc:map.qml"));

QQmlContext *qml_map = map->rootContext();
QGeoPath *path = new QGeoPath();
path->addCoordinate(*(new QGeoCoordinate(56.0831528053, 92.8405031454)));
path->addCoordinate(*(new QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 93)));
qml_map->setContextProperty("map_path", path);
```

Но к успеху меня это не очень привело... Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно написать свой класс, наследующий `QObject`:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGeoPath>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QTimer>

class PathController: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QGeoPath geopath READ geoPath WRITE setGeoPath NOTIFY geopathChanged)
public:
    PathController(QObject *parent=0):QObject(parent){}
    void test(){
        mGeoPath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.006355, 92.860984));
        mGeoPath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 93));
        mGeoPath.addCoordinate(QGeoCoordinate(56.1, 92.777));
        QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);

        QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this](){
            mGeoPath.translate(0.001, -0.01);
            emit geopathChanged();
        });
        timer->start(1000);

    }
    QGeoPath geoPath() const{return mGeoPath;}
    void setGeoPath(const QGeoPath &geoPath){
        if(geoPath == mGeoPath)
            return;
        mGeoPath = geoPath;
        emit geopathChanged();
    }

signals:
    void geopathChanged();
private:
    QGeoPath mGeoPath;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    PathController controller;
    controller.test();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pathController", &controller);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Plugin {
        id: osmMapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: osmMapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(56.006355, 92.860984)
        zoomLevel: 10

        MapPolyline {
            id: pl
            line.width: 3
            line.color: 'red'
        }
    }

    Connections{
        target: pathController
        onGeopathChanged: {
            var lines = []
            for(var i=0; i < pathController.geopath.size(); i++){
                lines[i] = pathController.geopath.coordinateAt(i)
            }
            pl.path = lines
        }
    }
}
```